# For what numbers $x$ is $D(x) = 2x - \sigma_1(x)$ equal to $\varphi(x)$?

Tags: divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

Let $\sigma_1$ be the classical sum-of-divisors function.

Let
$$D(x) = 2x - \sigma_1(x)$$
be the [*deficiency*](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$.

Let $\varphi(x)$ denote the [*Euler totient*](http://oeis.org/A000010).

Here is my question:

> For what numbers $x$ is $D(x) = 2x - \sigma_1(x)$ equal to $\varphi(x)$?

Trivially, $x=1$ answers my question.  But are there any others?

Comment: Only $x=1$ and $x=p$ for some prime natural number $p$ are the equality case.  Your other thread on a "sharp" bound of $D(x)$ should provide a clue on why that is.  You can first show that $x$ must be squarefree, and then $x$ can have at most one prime factor.

Comment: $\sigma(n) = \sum_{d | n} d$ and $\phi(n) = \sum_{d | n} d \mu(n/d)$ so $\frac{\sigma(n)+\phi(n)}{2} = \sum_{d | n} d \frac{1+\mu(n/d)}{2} \ge n$ and it is $= n$ iff $\frac{1+\mu(n/d)}{2} = 0$ whenever $d > 1$ i.e. iff $n$ is prime